# How to make a frame scrollable on python tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am attempting to make a frame in which I place buttons which are ingredients and when a person presses a button, it removes the button from the frame. I have tried many ways to implement this and the only proper way I could think of was to make the frame scrollable as I could not find a way to limit the row and the column sizes for the frame.

I have tried following some advice from chatgpt3 by making a popout window to act as a scrollable frame but this is 1. inconvenient and 2. doesn't even work because the scrolling doesn't work

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def create_popout_window(window):
    popout_window = tk.Toplevel(window)
    popout_window.title("Pop-out Window")

    # Create a canvas
    canvas = tk.Canvas(popout_window)
    canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

    # Add a scrollbar
    scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(popout_window, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
    scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

    # Configure the canvas
    canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

    # Create a frame inside the canvas
    scrollable_frame = tk.Frame(canvas, bg="pink", height=500, width=600)

    # Add widgets to the scrollable frame


    # Configure the canvas to contain the frame
    canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")

    def on_mousewheel(event):
        canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), "units")

    def bind_mousewheel(event):
        canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", on_mousewheel)

    def unbind_mousewheel(event):
        canvas.unbind_all("<MouseWheel>")

    # Bind mousewheel events

    popout_window.bind("<Enter>", bind_mousewheel)
    popout_window.bind("<Leave>", unbind_mousewheel)
    canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", on_mousewheel)

    return scrollable_frame
```

Comment: How do you want the buttons to appear? In a vertical list? Horizontal list? In a grid? Are the buttons are the same size? What constraints are you working with? The code you posted has no buttons so it's hard to know what you're asking.

Comment: sorry for the late response, i want the button to form in a square sort of list and they are all the same size, I was going to attempt to make it so when the button reaches the last visible grid in the rows, it would switch to the next column and then when the square is formed it would start going down a row again, however if this is not achievable I would prefer it to be vertical.  I have attempted to opt to use customtkinters scrollable frame as a temporary fix.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you wrote:

> i want the button to form in a square sort of list and they are all the same size, I was going to attempt to make it so when the button reaches the last visible grid in the rows, it would switch to the next column and then when the square is formed it would start going down a row again

If I understand what you want correctly, the simplest way to accomplish this is to put the buttons in a text widget. If you want the buttons to be in a grid then you'll need to make sure all of the buttons are the same size.

The advantage to using a text widget is that when you remove a button, all of the buttons will automatically rearrange themselves. You also get scrolling without any extra effort.

Here's a simple example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

container = tk.Text(root, wrap="char")
container.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

for i in range(40):
    name = f"button{i+1}"
    button = tk.Button(container, name=name, text=name, width=10)
    container.window_create("end", window=button)

container.configure(state="disabled")

tk.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot - wide]
[image: screenshot - tall]